# Here attachment is made on a particular ID ei., '00xx000000Sxxxx'; . I want to add this attachemnt on any id. Can I add {'!Contact.id'}?

Tags: apex

Here is my controller..

```
   public with sharing class AttachmentUploadController {

   public Attachment attachment {
 get {
  if (attachment == null)
    attachment = new Attachment();
  return attachment;
}
 set;
 }

public PageReference upload() {

attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
attachment.ParentId ='00xx000000Sxxxx';//  <====
attachment.IsPrivate = true;

 try {
   insert attachment;
  } catch (DMLException e) {
   ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
   return null;
 } finally {
  attachment = new Attachment();
 }

 ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment  uploaded successfully'));
return null;
}

}
```

I added the following

```
Contact Con = new Contact();attachment.ParentId='Con.ID';
```

Still no luck. Please help.

Comment: You are trying to add a string `'Con.ID'` to the ParentId. It is wrong because you need an SFDC ID. Remove quotes and try again: `attachment.ParentId = Con.ID;`

Comment: @mast0r I did what you said. I got this error..   
Errors

 

    Required fields are missing: [Parent]
    Error uploading attachment

Comment: If the Contact is not in the database it will not have an ID.  You need to insert it first.